# What makes a "medical" monitor?

Tags: display, specifications

Does anyone know the difference between a medical monitor and any other high-end LCD monitor that boasts accurate picture/colour reproduction? Is there something about it which makes it only suitable to be used in the medical field? Could you not use it for photo/video editing?

Comment: I'd imagine a medical-class monitor would be very accurate at reproducing images, but the refresh rate would be unimportant - there are very few real-time 60fps medical imaging techniques, after all.

Comment: Good point...so this would be the main reason why it's not a good idea to use it for editing HD video...along with what Manni said about screen surface?

Answer (score 5):

They have to pass a more rigid electromagnetic Interference testing then commercial equipment. You don't want computer, or other electrical equipment, causing interference in other equipment, like heart monitors.

Comment: Yep, the same with a lot of equipment, software, etc. used in the medical environment

Answer (score 3):

Many medical monitors work beyond 8-bit per channel, in 10 or 12 bit mode. Thus they support finer gradients then normal 8bit/channel LCD's. They need a special videocard to drive this too.

Answer (score 2):

Medical equipment must be able to survive disinfecting. I guess this has a pretty severe impact on the screen surface.

Answer (score 0):

Points that would matter

1. higher brightness levels and accurate color reproduction

   - rugged build
   - safety standards

A few references

1. Sony LMD series: [LMD-2140MD](http://salestores.com/sonylmd2140m.html) ,  [LMD-3250MD](http://www.pclaunches.com/monitors/sony_lmd3250md_full_32_medical_grade_lcd_monitor.php)

   - Dynamic Display: [Medical-Grade LCD Displays](http://www.dynamicdisplay.com/store.asp?pid=24271&catid=19925)

Answer (score -3):

There are also the monitors designed for viewing x-rays and such. The famous IBM T221 falls into this category: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T221

Comment: How does being "designed for viewing x-rays" cause the monitor to differ from one that was designed for general use?